# screen mirroring ubuntu to the new samsung smart tvs

Tags: wireless, samsung, screencast, chromecast, smart-tv

Im using 2019 samsung curved smart tv version UN55RU7300FXZA
and a ubuntu version 18.04.4 LTS

.I've tried using  the built inn chrome cast but the tv  noticed on my laptop but it tells me **source not supported**.But I've noticed in the connections menu that it works with only windows 8 and 10 versions.And i don't wan to buy a device ,has anyone found an app on the samsung apps or any wireless way  to connect.or some one who has their code on Github.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]